# Does Typescript automatically detect void functions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, inference

I’m a newbie in Typescript and in programming in general.

Instead of this:

```
function greet(greeting: string): void;
```

Can I use something like this? Is there any kind of inference?

```
function greet(greeting: string)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at TS docu about functions?

Comment: To be fair, finding a clear statement of a particular point of the TypeScript language is not always straightforward due to the fact that information is split across The Handbook, Release Notes, and GitHub Issues. For example, there are two different places where two opposite statements about type aliases are made, in one place it says type aliases *do not* create new types, in another place, it says that type aliases *do* create new types. Neither the chapter about functions nor the chapter about type inference answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in 95% of cases TypeScript will correctly infer the return type of a function. Exceptions to this include "tuples", which will be inferred as arrays, and anonymous objects which you may have already declared a type for.

In this case, no need to explicitly declare the return type as `void`, except for clarity of course.